# Friendly_id | Active Record not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-id

I follow the Railscast Episode [Pretty URLs with FriendlyId](http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid).

I'm on **Rails4** and using the **5.0 stable** branch on Friendly Id's Github Repo.

I followed the Tutorial:

My Model **Clip.rb**:

```
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :title, use: :slugged
```

My **Migration**:

```
rails g migration AddSlugToClips slug:string
```

**Edited** the Migration:

```
class AddSlugToClips < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :clips, :slug, :string
    add_index :clips, :slug
  end
end
```

With an empty Database i try to add a Clip and when i try to open it:

[image]

What am i missing?

**If i directly access the Vine via**

```
http://localhost:3000/clips/1
```

I get to the show page..

Comment: Can you confirm that the clip is added?

Comment: Yeap, i see it in the Index and in the DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok i found it, it has to do with the `Version of Friendly Id` you are using.

Finders are no longer overridden by default. If you want to do friendly finds, you must do `Model.friendly.find` rather than `Model.find.`

Answer (score 2):

It is because when you edit an clip and alter its title its slug will be updated.
So try to run the code with following changes.

```
class Clip < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    new_record?
  end
end


friendly_id :title, use: :slugged # you must do MyClass.friendly.find(params[:id])
#or
friendly_id :title, use: [:slugged, :finders] # you can now do MyClass.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: That is only if i EDIT the TITLE of a clip. But on my instance i upload a new clip and get the error.

Comment: Have you tried this friendly_id :title, use: :slugged # you must do MyClass.friendly.find('bar')

Comment: Hey amit. I finally found out what was wrong. Check out my Answer :)

Comment: Nice, please try to use the find method with my edited answer.

Comment: As of version 5.0, FriendlyId uses semantic versioning. One of the most important changes where that Finders are no longer overridden by default. If you want to do friendly finds, you must do Model.friendly.find rather than Model.find.

Comment: Nice, Instead of using `@clip = Clip.find_by_slug(params[:id])` use `friendly_id :title, use: [:slugged, :finders]`  `@clip = Clip.find(params[:id])` because if you are using Rails4 then try to avoid the use of find_by methods.

Comment: I gave you a usefull answer point for trying. Thank you, but for a fact those are the OLD Friedly ID Functions that in Rails4 we dont have to recall. :)

Comment: You are right @The Mini John, I am just saying that we can use the find method by adding :finders addon.